send emails to new user from laravel without smtp
I am trying to send mails from Laravel project hosted on hostinger.
I have to send mails from different mails like noreply@domain.com, seo@domain.com, developer@domain.com etc. In PHP I can use mail() to send mails and it's working in Laravel as well, but I want to some best solution.
I have tried using
Mail::from('hr@xyz.com', 'HR Department')->to('sadsa@gmail.com')->send(new welcome);

I am facing Method Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::from does not exist. while using this method. Guide me to send mails properly from Laravel and hosting server.

it's laravel 10

The from call would go in the Mailable(welcome), not the Mail call.
